# Running script for a group to access functions within group parts

Tags: lua, roblox

I was just wondering in roblox if anyone has ever come upon a situation where they needed to run scripts from another script. My situation is that I am making a control point system for a game. I need to be able to know if the other points are captured in order to capture the next ones so I am attempting to write a controller on top of it but i am not sure exactly how to access the functions from within the control point script.

Comment: Could you give us some example code, and also some links to the code that you want to include? We will need to know more about your specific situation in order to give you a good answer. (See also [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).)

Comment: basically the way it needs to be accessed is the following, Control group script accesses the part script, that part being the parts in the control group.

Comment: There shouldn't need any code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! ROBLOX provides a very useful feature called ModuleScripts for the very purpose of calling scripts from other scripts. [The icon for ModuleScripts looks the same as the icon for regular Scripts except with a little brick in the bottom-right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcN7N.png)

The way it works is that regular Scripts can call ModuleScripts in the game using the special `require()` function. The easiest way to explain this is with an example.

To begin, let's imagine that we have a Script and a ModuleScript. The Script will be located at `game.Workspace.normalScript`, and the ModuleScript will be located inside a brick called `part` at  `game.Workspace.part.moduleScript`.

`moduleScript` will contain the following code:

```
script.Parent.Transparency = .5 --"Parent" is the part since this ModuleScript is located inside the part
```

Now, `normalScript` will contain the following code:

```
require(game.Workspace.part.moduleScript)
```

When you run the game, `normalScript` will execute `moduleScript`, changing the transparency of `part` to .5. When one calls `require()` on a ModuleScript, it will act as though it were a normal function being called. `moduleScript` acted as though it were a function, and ModuleScripts in general act the same way as functions for the most part.

This also means that ModuleScripts can return values like functions. For example, if we have the following code in `moduleScript`:

```
return 3+3
```

Now, our script will contain the following code:

```
local number = require(game.Workspace.moduleScript)
print(number) --> 6
```

This code will print "6" to the console since `moduleScript` returned 6. As you might guess, this means that ModuleScripts have many more uses than simply remotely executing code.

Here are two more examples of uses of ModuleScripts:

1) Returning functions:

`moduleScript`:

```
return function()
    print("hey")
end
```

`normalScript`:

```
local func = require(game.Workspace.moduleScript)
func() --> hey
```

2) Returning modules such as `apple` below:

`moduleScript`:

```
local apple = {}
apple.flavor = "sweet"
return apple
```

`normalScript`:

```
local fruit = require(game.Workspace.moduleScript)
print(fruit.flavor) --> sweet
```

These are rather silly examples of ModuleScript uses, but ModuleScripts can actually be very powerful tools. For some cool examples, visit the [ROBLOX Wiki page on ModuleScripts](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/ModuleScript) and scroll about halfway down.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it. I have another question up right now actually and you seem pretty experienced.

Comment: @Tykota Yeah, of course! I hope it helped. And yeah, I saw it but honestly I wasn't really sure how to answer it because there wasn't much to work with. Do you have a link to your game?

Comment: @Tykota Okay, I took a closer look at that question you posted. Could you show where you assigned the buttons to those variables? I would have commented on that post itself, but I don't have enough reputation, haha. (I'd appreciate it if you marked my answer as accepted c:)